# Setting attribute of point if it matches point from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, fields-attributes, overlapping-features

I have two layers of points:

- The first layer contains points which have an attribute called `"svf"` with values between `0` and `1`
- The second layer contains a subset (in terms of location) of the points in the first layer

The green points are from the first layer, the big blue ones are from the second layer:

[image]

What I want to do now is to set the `"svf"` value to `0` for all points in the first layer, who have a corresponding point in the second layer.

I tried it using the "Join attributes by location" tool, but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: "Select by location" followed by "Field calculator"

Comment: @MrXsquared they are probably a little apart, because both layers were derived from different polylines with 'Generate points (pixel centroids) along line'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select the nearby points using ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression), then you can open the calculator to update the desired field.

The expression would make use of [`overlay_nearest()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest) to find points having a nearby point in the 2nd layer. You must specify a maximal acceptable distance between the points (beware of the coordinate system unit)

```
overlay_nearest('layer_2_name', max_distance:=0.1)
```

[image]