# How do I eliminate Grid points that are less than a desired distance from my polygon boundary

Tags: qgis, google-earth, samplepoints

I'm performing a sampling study using a systematic sampling grid. I have calculated that I need to establish 71 plots that fall within polygons in the area of interest and I have calculated that the plots need to be approx 35m from each other.

When I fix the grid across the AOI with the 35mx35m specifications, I get around 90-100 grid points that fall within the polygons.

I think this is because of the irregular shapes of the polygons and that I am trying to establish a square grid over the AOI.

To systematically reduce the number of grid points, I want to remove points that fall less than 5.6m (plot radius) from the boundaries of all polygons. I need to replicate this process for 22 other Villages. My polygons for each village are grouped together into a KML for that village and so I don't want to do this manually

So far I have tried using: `distance($geometry, geometry(get_feature('polygon_layer_name', 'attribute', 'value'))) <= 5.6`
where,

[image]

I have used the KML name.

I don't know what I should keep for attribute or value, so I tried using the Name attribute of my KML and did not set a value.

There is no error in the function, but no results either. So, I repeated with different distances 10m, 15m, 20m. The result is the same.

Comment: You could buffer your polygon by the distance, and then create your points.

Comment: are your datasets in a projected CRS otherwise 5.6 degrees probably finds everything

Comment: You can select using `overlay_nearest` https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416065/setting-attribute-of-point-if-it-matches-point-from-another-layer-in-qgis/416088#416088

Comment: Maybe my answer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333709/insert-n-points-equally-distributed-into-many-polygons/333822#333822) question can help

Comment: @Erik, yes I tried this and it worked fine. Thank you everyone for your contribution.